# Google Maps Api wheelchair accessible places filtering

Tags: asp.net

My team is creating a map of wheelchair-accessible travel destinations.

A few months ago I discovered that Google developers added finally the option to mark every place on the map as wheelchair-accessible. We really want to use this function in our app and the web site, allowing our users to sort all accessible places and to show only accessible places in our region. Unfortunately we haven't been able to figure out how to do this.

Does anybody know how to filter destinations this way using the Google Maps API?

Comment: Have you checked their API documentation?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please avoid including irrelevant personal information on Stack Overflow and instead focus on your actual question. See [ask]. It is especially important not to promote your website unless you want to be confused with a spammer.